# How to check if a path is in PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python, path, pythonpath, sys.path

How can I check that a path is in PYTHONPATH?

I've tried to do:

```py
def path_is_in_pythonpath(path):
    return str(path) in sys.path
```

But it didn't work sometimes when running on Windows. The path was in PYTHONPATH but the check returned False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that Windows paths are case insensitive. This applied even to drive letters, which can sometimes be lowercase despite the common sense that they're always uppercase letters.

[os.path.normcase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normcase) does the job of normalizing Windows paths to lowercase appropriately.

This will correctly check if `path` is in `PYTHONPATH`, OS independently:

```py
def path_is_in_pythonpath(path):
    path = os.path.normcase(path)
    return any(os.path.normcase(sp) == path for sp in sys.path)
```